# Path structure of font-awesome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

My file structure is like this:

```
folder/
|--- controllers/
|    |--- base/
|         |--- index.php
|--- assets/
|    |--- fonts/
|         |--- font-awesome/
|              |--- FontAwesome.otf
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.eot
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.svg
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.ttf
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.woff
|    |--- css/
|         |--- font-awesome/
|              |--- font-awesome.css
```

I want to add the font-awesome css from index.php. However, I can't do that. I had tried adding like the following:

But with no luck. What should be the path to add the css of font-awesome. Also, since I changed the by-default structure of font-awesome path, should I need to change anything within the font-awesome.css file?If so, what changes?

Comment: ../../assets/css/font-awesome/font-awesome.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call the file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/font-awesome/font-awesome.css">
```

then you will need to do some changes since you change the directory:
in the file font-awesome.ccs make sure the paths are correct according to your file hierarchy.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
  src: url('../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

hope it helped

or you go back to the by-default structure of font-awesome:

```
|--- assets/
|    |--- font-awesome/
|         |--- fonts/
|              |--- FontAwesome.otf
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.eot
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.svg
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.ttf
|              |--- font-awesome-webfont.woff
|         |--- css/
|              |--- font-awesome.css
```

and call the file with the normal method without doing any changes to the css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

Comment: No need to change the paths in file in the file font-awesome.ccs. Its root is css directory.

Comment: by default the css folder and fonts folder are in fontawesome folder, but he made changes and seperated theme, so he needs to correct them.

Comment: Actually, the css file is linked but the fonts are not showing. They are coming as boxes. All of them. But by inspecting the elements, I can see that the css of the font is linked correctly.

Comment: Edited your code @FBarawi and now, it's working perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two folders back, then forward...
Try this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/font-awesome/font-awesome.css">
```

And you don't need to change any other path I think.